# Running spring batch job in unix

Tags: java, unix, spring-batch

I am receiving an error while running this command in unix:

```
java -cp "code-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/*"
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
iJob.xml processJob
```

The error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [iJob.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [iJob.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Would you please give us more information?

Comment: your command should work if the file `iJob.xml` is in the directory where you run the `java` command. Otherwise you need to point to its absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

`iJob.xml` is in the wrong location probably.

Correct this path in your main class where you are loading the xml configuration file would fix your issue.